# EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend’ ^ SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Tags: django, email, installation

hi i am getting the following error

```
   EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend’
                                                                 ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

my email settings under settings.py

```
 STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/mail_app/'),

]

# email settings
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend’
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.drenkdjdna.com’
EMAIL_USE_TSL = True
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'dm@mksdnknf.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'kdjkjfn'
```

Comment: The quote at the end is not a `'` but a *forward quote* (`’`). Remove the `’` and replace it with `'`'.

Comment: notice the coloring on the next line.